# query works on firefox but not on ie and chrome

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query right here:

```
$query_1 = "select * from test.users where app_id='$app_id' and user_id='".$user_id."'";
    $resource_1 = mysql_query($query_1);
    $result_1 = mysql_fetch_object($resource_1);

    var_dump($result_1);
```

For some weird, strange reason, the query above output the correct result in Firefox, but on IE and chrome it outputs false like the following:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>boolean</small> <font color='#75507b'>false</font>
```

Any idea what is causing this to happen? It doesn't make any sense to me at all.

Thanks for any help

Comment: No idea why that would happen, but can we see how you populate $user_id, and $app_id?  Just something to help debug the weirdness :\

Comment: Show us what the output is from Firefox, to compare with IE's / Chrome's version. Something else is causing this. PHP/SQL are server-side, not client-side.

Comment: Instead of fetch_object(), try using fetch_array() or fetch_assoc(). Try using mysqli_* instead of mysql_* because it is depreciated. Also, can you post more of your code? How do you manage the data?

Comment: This shouldn't be browser dependent, the php/sql finishes executing before the html is sent to the browser so it must be a problem with how `$user_id` and/or `$app_id` are getting populated.

Comment: Don't expect any `Magical Answers` to suddenly appear. We asked you for more information. If you can't provide it, then we can't help you. *I'm outta here.* Good luck with that.

Comment: @Aerojun, fetch_object returns a stdClass object with the columns being public properties. It has nothing to do with the problem described here.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has way to many flaws to be able to properly debug.
It probably works on Firefox because the page is cached, but it should not work in either browser.

Try the following:

```
<?php
$sql = "select * from test.users where app_id=:app_id and user_id=:user_id;";

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=yourDBname');

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':app_id', $appId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':user_id', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Also, try looking into PHP PDO because it will help you avoid quite a few problems.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Hope it helps,
Denis

Comment: PS: If the code fixes your problem please do not forget to mark the answer as accepted. It might help others as well. Thanks.